# React Bootstrap Best Practices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react bootstrap with my app. I'm wondering what is the best practice for creating grids. The react-bootstrap docs call for

```
<Col xs={12} md={8} />
```

But this means i need to import Grid and Row in every component.

I have been writing like

```
<row>
  <div className ="col-md-12">
```

is this the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: "but this means i need to import Grid and Row in every component" --- and?

Comment: i just thought that seemed like lots of repeating, but if thats the way it is then theres nothing i can do

Comment: It is a "repeating", so?

Comment: changed all the files, tks

Comment: Hey @caffeinescript based on one of your other comments it seems like you are import each individual item from react-bootstrap with separate lines of code which does get repetitive.  Try using something like  `import { Image, Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';` which will definitely cut down on how many imports you are using.

Comment: oh ok thanks @Pljeskavica

Comment: @Pljeskavica importing components as a whole will include whole react-bootstrap into bundle.js which makes the bundle.js size huge. Better to import each component individually like `import Image from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Image`

Comment: I agree with @MorganCheng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<div className ="col-md-12">` violates encapsulation, it exposes inner implementation of grid column to outside. And it may lead to maintenance problems. For instance, if in next Bootstrap version grid changes somehow, you should find all `<div className ="col-md-12">` and replace them manually, in case of `<Col xs={12} md={8} />` all you should do is to update library.

Answer (score 0):

To require the library in your js file, here is the example [getting started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html)

For example if you use commonjs:

```
var Col = require('react-bootstrap').Col;
```

Comment: thanks, for es6 ive been using `import Grid from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Grid';`